# How to reformulate (or model differently) the sum of fractions in the objective of integer program?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, operations-research

I have the following (integer) program:

$ \max \sum_{i\in I} \frac{a_i}{b_i + \sum_{j\in J} c_{ij} x_{ij}} $

s.t. $ x \in X $

$ x_{ij}\in \{0,1\}, \quad\forall i\in I \wedge j\in J $,

where $ a_i > 0 $, $ b_i > 0 $, and $ c_{ij} > 0 $, for all $ i\in I $ and $ j\in J $. Here, $ x $ represents the vector of binary variables $ x_{ij} $ and $ X $ is a nonempty convex set defined by a set of linear inequalities/constraints.

Is there a way to reformulate it or to write *an equivalent program* that is not much harder to solve?

Of course, it can be transformed in a straightforward fashion by setting the objective as $ \max \sum_{i\in I} y_i $, where $ y_i \leq  \frac{a_i}{b_i + \sum_{j\in J} c_{ij} x_{ij}}, ~y_i\geq 0 ~(\forall i\in I) $. This will lead to *additional constraints*

$ b_i y_i + \sum_{j\in J} c_{ij} z_{ij} \leq a_i, ~\forall i\in I $,

where $ z_{ij} = x_{ij} y_i $ is a product of binary and continuous variable (easily linearized). But the solver runtime can be greatly affected if $ |J| $ is large.

If the objective is not a sum, then this would be a special case of linear-fractional programming, and thus an equivalent *minimization* model could be easily written.

Therefore, my question is if there is *an another way*, that does not involve too many additional constraints, i.e., if there is, maybe, a way to write an equivalent model in the terms of optimal solutions?

Comment: The post is changed, so that only summations are used.

Comment: X is a convex nonempty set. The variables $ x_{ij} $ should satisfy some constraints, which define that set X.

Comment: Where does this optimization problem come from? At first glance, it looks kind of hopeless. However, knowing its origin can help one reformulate it in a way that is less hopeless.